# Subquery returning more than 1 row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an artists table and an artists_alias table.  artists_alias contains all possible names for the artists.

My query, to grab artist data on multiple artists, looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT artist.artist_id, artist.artist_name
        FROM artists artist
        WHERE artist.artist_id IN (3,9,500);";
```

Now, I want to also include any known aliases which can be 1 or X.  Can I fetch this information within the query above?  Or is this a separate query?

I was thinking about doing something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT artist.artist_id, artist.artist_name, 
       (SELECT * FROM artists_alias WHERE [???])....";
```

But I get the error message "Subquery returns more than 1 row" -- am I making this more complicated than it is?  Can this be one query?

I'd be happy to have the aliases comma separated, so for instance a return row might look like: 3, "ben folds five", "ben folds five,benfolds,ben folds five, folds five"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a `LEFT JOIN` against `artist_alias` to retrieve these.  And if you want them comma-separated, use the aggregate [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

The `LEFT JOIN` is used so that a row returns even if an artist has no aliases associated.

One row per alias (which duplicates the artist info per row):

```
SELECT
  artist.artist_id, 
  artist.artist_name,
  /* Retrieves all cols from artists_alias. SELECT only what you need... */
  artists_alias.*
FROM
  artist
  /* Assuming there's an artists_alias.artist_id. Substitute the correct column name */
  LEFT JOIN artists_alias ON artist.artist_id = artists_alias.artist_id
WHERE artist.artist_id IN (3, 9, 500)
```

Or the comma-separated list of aliases via `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT
  artist.artist_id, 
  artist.artist_name,
  /* Substitute the correct column name for the actual alias */
  GROUP_CONCAT(artists_alias.alias) AS all_aliases
FROM
  artist
  LEFT JOIN artists_alias ON artist.artist_id = artists_alias.artist_id
WHERE artist.artist_id IN (3, 9, 500)
GROUP BY 
  artist.artist_id,
  artist.artist_name
```

Comment: Ah, this is great!  thank you much!  For some reason, I was thinking the LEFT JOIN wouldn't grab ALL values.  Shrug.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return all the aliases in one row, then use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT a.artist_id, a.artist_name,
       group_concat(aa.alias) as aliases
FROM artists artist left outer join
     artists_alias aa
     on a.artist_id = aa.artist_id
WHERE at.artist_id IN (3,9,500)
group by a.artist_id, a.artist_name
```

Answer (score -1):

put limit 1 in the end.

select * from tble where a=1 limit 1;

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem, it just masks the symptom.